# Redis search for keys with a value

Tags: ruby, redis, redis-rails

How do you search for keys with a value in Ruby? For example get all KEYS where the value is "somevalue".

My keys are

"xyz" => {:status=> "connected", :topic=> "ABC"}

"PQR" => {:status=> "connected", :topic=> "ABC"}

Now I need to find all the KEYS where topic is "ABC"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find key by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12745818/find-key-by-value)

Answer (score 6):

Regardless the programming language, to do this efficiently you'll need to maintain an "index" key that maps somevalue to the key names. Using a Set or a Sorted Set for this is what you should usually do - i.e. add new key names to it and remove them according to their values - and get that key's contents when you want to "search".

There are some libraries (i.e. gems) that may provide this sort of functionality ready to use - look into the most excellent [Ohm](http://ohm.keyvalue.org/) in your case.

**EDIT**

> My keys are xyz => {:status=> "connected", :topic=> "ABC"} PQR => {:status=> "connected", :topic=> "ABC"} Now I need to find all the KEYS where topic is "ABC"

I would store xyz's value as a String or a Hash (depending on whether I need to update/read just parts of it or not). Then I would `SADD topic:ABC xyz` and do `SMEMBERS` or `SSCAN` on it to get the names of all keys with that topic. I'd also try to remember to `SREM` the relevant member from topic:ABC when I `DEL` its key...

Comment: My keys are

xyz => {:status=> "connected", :topic=> "ABC"}

PQR => {:status=> "connected", :topic=> "ABC"}

Now I need to find all the KEYS where topic is "ABC"

Comment: Hi I am doing mapped_hmset "xyz", { status: "connected",topic: "ABC" } . Now how to move forward. I guess if I do smembers it will give me all the values in "XYZ". How can search with "ABC"

Comment: Sure, if that's what you need. Follow that with the `SADD` and wrap it with a `MULTI/EXE` block for atomicity.

Comment: I think if I do SMEMBERS it will print all the values in that particular key not searching

Comment: `SMEMBER topic:ABC` will return all key names who have :topic=>"ABC" if you took care of that as explained. The order of key names shouldn't matter unless I grossly misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on which version of redis you can use [getkeys](http://redis.io/commands/command-getkeys) on redis >= 2.8.13 or you could use [keys](http://redis.io/commands/keys) command taking care some performance issues (if you have few keys should not be a problem but if you have a large amount of keys take care with that, because keys command will block redis for a few moment in order to get all keys)

If you are running redis 2.8 you'll be able to use [scan](http://redis.io/commands/scan) command instead keys.

**EDIT:** A recently added page in Redis' documentation provides more information about [Secondary indexing with Redis](http://redis.io/topics/indexes) and covers this case under the [Non range indexes](http://redis.io/topics/indexes#non-range-indexes) section. Additional topics in it include:

- [Simple numerical indexes with sorted sets](http://redis.io/topics/indexes#simple-numerical-indexes-with-sorted-sets)
- [Lexicographical indexes](http://redis.io/topics/indexes#lexicographical-indexes)
- [Composite indexes](http://redis.io/topics/indexes#composite-indexes)
- [Representing and querying graphs using an hexastore](http://redis.io/topics/indexes#representing-and-querying-graphs-using-an-hexastore)
- [Multi dimensional indexes](http://redis.io/topics/indexes#multi-dimensional-indexes)

Comment: I disagree - `COMMAND GETKEYS` isn't related to this at all, please RTFM. `KEYS` is not a command you want to use... ever (forget blocking, that's child's play, OOM is what you should fear). Regardless, both `KEYS` and `SCAN` take time and resources so they're a poor choice if you want a quick response.

Comment: I agree on that, and I said that using keys command is not a good thing to do on production and is not a safe solucion. But is part of the redis solution and commands that you could use if you need to (for example if you are debugging on development or reading from a slave node or whatever you want).

Comment: If you're a dev or an admin you can also do `rm -rf /` :) `SCAN` isn't as bad as `KEYS`, but it still requires O(N) to traverse the keyspace (not to mention sending back the key names and then doing a read on each for the value...). As a debugging/ad-hoc approach, sure, whatever. As an approach to solve an application requirement - never! (BTW, see Redis Commandment VI: https://gist.github.com/itamarhaber/d125cec7ebc5ec3886ab)

Comment: Haha!! nice gist!!! I agree on that, but If I were you, I would never do rm -fr / , is not a good practice ;)