# how to search the keys by values in redis?

Tags: redis

I have two different keys have same values in redis. If I know one of the key and their value, I need to know the another key.

I am storing list type Values for these keys

Comment: Redis is (in essence) a key-value server. You use keys to look up values, not the other way around. In your case, you should create an inverted index (list items being keys, and list key names being their values)

Comment: More information about 2ndary indexing in Redis: http://redis.io/topics/indexes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find key by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12745818/find-key-by-value)